# select distinct(username) running too slow

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I have a postgres table like this
`id, username`

The question is why request like this is running too slow

```
select count(distinct(username)) as cnt from client
```

I've tried to create an index like this
`CREATE INDEX idx_client_username ON client(username);`

Update.

Here are two queries that I tried.

`EXPLAIN (ANALYZE) select count(distinct(username)) as cnt from client`

```
"Aggregate  (cost=14430.43..14430.43 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=1813.138..1813.139 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  ->  Seq Scan on client  (cost=0.00..14064.80 rows=731265 width=10) (actual time=0.018..120.601 rows=731282 loops=1)"
"Planning Time: 0.450 ms"

"Execution Time: 1813.169 ms"
```

`EXPLAIN ANALYZE select count(*) as cnt from (select from client group by username) t;`

```
"Aggregate  (cost=14814.21..14814.22 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=461.042..461.043 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  ->  HashAggregate  (cost=14430.43..14607.56 rows=59044 width=10) (actual time=408.084..449.494 rows=195382 loops=1)"
"        Group Key: client.username"
"        ->  Seq Scan on client  (cost=0.00..14064.80 rows=731265 width=10) (actual time=0.023..136.145 rows=731282 loops=1)"
"Planning Time: 0.490 ms"
"Execution Time: 463.872 ms"
```

Comment: count is notorious slow

Comment: This is going nowhere without an `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` of the query. Do that and post the results to your question. Also have you run a `ANALYZE` by itself on the table?

Comment: I have read somewhere that _count distinct_ is old and tired. Try `select count(*) as cnt from (select from client group by username) t;`

Comment: Note that the parentheses around the column name `(username)` are useless

Comment: @Stefanov.sm I tried your query and it is really faster. Can you please take a look at original question? I updated it.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I updated question with EXPLAIN ANALYZE. Can you please take a look?

Comment: What version of PostgreSQL?  You now have it nearly 4 times faster, is that still too slow?

Comment: @jjanes actually 400ms is enough for me yes

Comment: Have you run `ANALYZE client`?